# Is there way to remove element from list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there function in Wolfram Mathematica for removing element from original list? 
For example

```
a={1,2,3};
DeleteFrom[a,1];
a

a={2,3}
```

If it is absent can anyone give example of efficient variant of such function?
(I know that there is function Delete() but it will create new list. This is not good if list is big)

Comment: If you have a good criterion which tells when an item must be deleted, you can use the `Select` function, which selects item NOT to be deleted.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to drop the first element from a list `a` the statement

```
Drop[a,1]
```

returns a list the same as `a` without its first element.  Note that this does not update `a`.  To do that you could assign the result to `a`, eg

```
a = Drop[a,1]
```

Note that this is probably exactly what `Delete` is doing behind the scenes; first making a copy of `a` without its first element, then assigning the name `a` to that new list, then freeing the memory used by the old list.

Comparing destructive updates and non-destructive updates in Mathematica is quite complicated and can take one deep into the system's internals.  You'll find a lot about the subject on the [Stack Exchange Mathematica site.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Real task is more complex. There is big list(10000000 elements) of data. It is needed to remove some elements from list by some createria. Usually it is needed to remove 30-40 percents of elements. Anyway thank you for link.

Comment: You point up one of the serious problems with SO and its ilk.  You can only get answers to the questions you ask, not to the questions you want answered.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you change the length of a list in *Mathematica* you cause a reallocation of the list, which takes O(n) rather than O(1) time.  Though no "DeleteFrom" function exists, if it did it would be no faster than `a = Delete[a, x]`.

If you can create in advance a list of all the elements you wish to delete and delete them all at once you will get much better performance.   If you cannot you will have to find another way to formulate your problem.  I suggest you join us on the proper Stack Exchange site if you have additional questions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assign the element to an empty sequence and it will removed from the list.  This works for any element.

```
In[1] := a = {1,2,3}
Out[1]= {1,2,3}

In[2] := a[[1]] = Sequence[]
Out[2] = Sequence[]

In[3] := a
Out[3] = {2,3}
```

Yes Mathematica tends towards non-destructive programming, but the programmers at Wolfram are pretty clever folks and the code seems to run pretty fast.  It hard to believe they would always copy a whole list to change one element, i.e. not make any optimizations.

Comment: Note that `Definition[a]` still returns `a = {Sequence[], 2, 3}`. So the element is not removed but is replaced by `Sequence[]`.

Comment: The empty sequences go away as one works with the list.  Note b = 1 * a; Definition[b] returns b={2,3} .

Answer (score 0):

Improving the `user3446498`'s answer, you can do the following:

```
In[1] := a = {1,2,3};

In[2] := a[[1]] = Nothing;

In[3] := a
Out[3] = {2,3}

In[4] := a == {2,3}
Out[4] = True
```

this `Nothing` symbol was introduced in in the 10th version (2015), see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions from @user3446498 and @pmsoltani **won't actually delete** the element. Test:

```js
a = {1, 2, 3};
a[[2]] = Sequence[]; (* or Nothing *)
--a[[1]];
++a[[2]];

a
```

They both output `{0, 4, 3}`, while `{0, 4}` is expected.

Replacing 2nd line with `a = Delete[a, 2];` would work.

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica, you can drop the first and last elements from a list using the `Most` and `Rest` functions. Here's how you can do it:

originalList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
droppedList = Most[Rest[originalList]];

In this example, `Most` is used to drop the last element (`Rest` would drop the first element), effectively removing both the first and last elements from the list `originalList`. The result will be stored in the variable `droppedList`.

Here's the result:

droppedList = {2, 3, 4}